# Parsing xml without namespace

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a parsing problem that appears when I try to parse from a String, containg a xml, to a org.w3c.dom.Document.

Here is a example of a xml String that i'm trying to parse:

```
<enviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
   <idLote>123</idLote>
   <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    ...
   </NFe>
</enviNFe>
```

The problem is, that after que String had been parsed, by the following code:

```
private Document documentFactory(String xml) throws SAXException,      
    IOException, ParserConfigurationException, DocumentException, TransformerException {    

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();      
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);    

    Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(      
        new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));    

return document;    
}
```

The tag NFe loads without the namespace (xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")

I want to know why this happens, and what I could do to solve this.

Any help will be great.
Thanks, and sorry for my english.

------EDIT----
For better understanding:

This xml will be signed right after de parsing, and will be sent to a Government's server(Brazil).
After this, I do another request to this server, to verify if it was processed or not. If it was, I will get a positive response in case of any error.
The first problem I had, was that the xml was malformed. This happened because I was sending the xml without that namespace in the tag NFe.
To solve this I added it(namespace) right in the File, after the xml had being signed.
This problem in fact had been solved, but another occurred: the difference in the signature.
Because I signs the xml without the namespace, and send with it.

Comment: side note, don't convert your String back to bytes in order to parse it, use `parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)))`.  (otherwise you risk corrupting the xml depending on the default platform character encoding).

Comment: other than my previous comment, your code looks correct.  the bug must be elsewhere.  can you show the code where you are checking the namespace?

Comment: well, to check if the namespace is loaded or not, I use this:
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
xform.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(out));
System.out.println(out.toString());

Comment: I had tried your suggestion, but happens the same. 
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can put together from your various comments, i think you are misunderstanding how xml works.  you indicate that you manually added the namespace to the `NFe` element.  however, in your xml example, the `NFe` node *already has that namespace*.

In this xml:

```
<enviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
   <idLote>123</idLote>
   <NFe>
    ...
   </NFe>
</enviNFe>
```

*all* of the nodes have the "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" namespace.  by putting the `xmlns="..."` attribute on the parent node, the namespace is applied to that node and *all* of the child nodes with the same prefix (in this case, no prefix).

Comment: hmmmmm, right. So this is more problematic. The real problem is that the server demands this namespace annotation. If a send a xml without it, a get an error, and if I send with it I get another. I must find other way to compute the signature, I think. 
An important point here, I can't change the server implementation.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @lucianohdr - are you canonicalizing the xml before signing it?  that is generally required whenever xml is signed.

Comment: Yes, this is being done. Based on what you said about the way xml works, I tried another way to solve this. I unbind the NFe from enviNFe, so the namespace was loaded, and a could sign the xml correctly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the correct document.  To test it you can just walk through your document.

```
doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getNamespaceURI();
```

Or try to get the tag by it's name:

```
NodeList tags = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", "NFe");
```

Comment: I edited question in order to clarify this. In fact, I need to sign this xml with the namespace. Thank's for your attention

Comment: resign it then?  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: No, it is signed only once. What I need is to load the xml with the both tags with namespaces, or find a way to add this later(before the process of signing).

Comment: that xml is being loaded with the namespace.  I don't think I'm following you.  When you are talking about signing are you talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature if so you can't change the xml once it is signed.

Comment: yes, I meant it(XML_Signature). Right, now I know that I can't, haha

Comment: I think I expressed myself badly, after the parser, the tag NFe instead of "<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">", is being loaded this way "<NFe>".

Comment: No it is not.  Please show us code that doesn't load it correctly.